# how to display json object with two array in html by using two for loops

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have this form:

[image: Form image]

Personal details in storing into personal table and book into book table.

The table is linked by the `Id` field in personal table and `UserId` field in book table. 
5 books can be inserted against 1 personal information. userId of 5 books records will be same as personal information Id.

So, now to the problem:

I am echoing both tables data as json array (2 arrays) in php and wanted to display it in html via loop. 
Personal information is getting displayed but books are not displaying. It might also be possible that my approach is not good.
So, please give me some good alternative if you have any.

**JSON data:**

```
{
   "personaldetails":[
      {
         "id":"79",
         "FirstName":"Elon",
         "MiddleName":"",
         "LastName":"Musk",
         "Gender":"Male",
         "Location":"New York",
         "Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com",
         "Mobile":"1234567890"
      },
      {
         "id":"78",
         "FirstName":"Elon",
         "MiddleName":"",
         "LastName":"Musk",
         "Gender":"Male",
         "Location":"New York",
         "Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com",
         "Mobile":"1234567890"
      },
      {
         "id":"77",
         "FirstName":"Elon",
         "MiddleName":"",
         "LastName":"Musk",
         "Gender":"Male",
         "Location":"New York",
         "Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com",
         "Mobile":"1234567890"
      },
      {
         "id":"76",
         "FirstName":"Elon",
         "MiddleName":"",
         "LastName":"Musk",
         "Gender":"Male",
         "Location":"New York",
         "Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com",
         "Mobile":"1234567890"
      },
      {
         "id":"75",
         "FirstName":"Elon",
         "MiddleName":"",
         "LastName":"Musk",
         "Gender":"Male",
         "Location":"New York",
         "Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com",
         "Mobile":"1234567890"
      },
      {
         "id":"74",
         "FirstName":"Elon",
         "MiddleName":"",
         "LastName":"Musk",
         "Gender":"Male",
         "Location":"New York",
         "Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com",
         "Mobile":"1234567890"
      },
      {
         "id":"73",
         "FirstName":"Elon",
         "MiddleName":"",
         "LastName":"Musk",
         "Gender":"Male",
         "Location":"New York",
         "Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com",
         "Mobile":"1234567890"
      },
      {
         "id":"72",
         "FirstName":"Elon",
         "MiddleName":"",
         "LastName":"Musk",
         "Gender":"Male",
         "Location":"New York",
         "Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com",
         "Mobile":"1234567890"
      },
      {
         "id":"71",
         "FirstName":"Elon",
         "MiddleName":"",
         "LastName":"Musk",
         "Gender":"Male",
         "Location":"New York",
         "Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com",
         "Mobile":"1234567890"
      },
      {
         "id":"70",
         "FirstName":"Elon",
         "MiddleName":"",
         "LastName":"Musk",
         "Gender":"Male",
         "Location":"New York",
         "Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com",
         "Mobile":"1234567890"
      },
      {
         "id":"69",
         "FirstName":"Elon",
         "MiddleName":"",
         "LastName":"Musk",
         "Gender":"Male",
         "Location":"New York",
         "Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com",
         "Mobile":"1234567890"
      },
      {
         "id":"68",
         "FirstName":"Elon",
         "MiddleName":"",
         "LastName":"Musk",
         "Gender":"Male",
         "Location":"New York",
         "Email":"elonmusk@tesla.com",
         "Mobile":"1234567890"
      }
   ],
   "bookdetails":[
      {
         "UserId":"79",
         "BookTitle":"who am i",
         "BookGenre":"inspiration",
         "BookWriter":"modi",
         "BookDescription":"this book is all about the struggle one faces all his life.no matter what he does he never get any attention"
      },
      {
         "UserId":"79",
         "BookTitle":"a walk to remember",
         "BookGenre":"romance",
         "BookWriter":"peter",
         "BookDescription":"a wall in the rainy season where all "
      },
      {
         "UserId":"78",
         "BookTitle":"who am i",
         "BookGenre":"inspiration",
         "BookWriter":"modi",
         "BookDescription":"this book is all about the struggle one faces all his life.no matter what he does he never get any attention"
      },
      {
         "UserId":"78",
         "BookTitle":"a walk to remember",
         "BookGenre":"romance",
         "BookWriter":"peter",
         "BookDescription":"a wall in the rainy season where all "
      },
      {
         "UserId":"77",
         "BookTitle":"who am i",
         "BookGenre":"inspiration",
         "BookWriter":"modi",
         "BookDescription":"this book is all about the struggle one faces all his life.no matter what he does he never get any attention"
      },
      {
         "UserId":"77",
         "BookTitle":"a walk to remember",
         "BookGenre":"romance",
         "BookWriter":"peter",
         "BookDescription":"a wall in the rainy season where all "
      },
      {
         "UserId":"76",
         "BookTitle":"who am i",
         "BookGenre":"inspiration",
         "BookWriter":"modi",
         "BookDescription":"this book is all about the struggle one faces all his life.no matter what he does he never get any attention"
      },
      {
         "UserId":"76",
         "BookTitle":"a walk to remember",
         "BookGenre":"romance",
         "BookWriter":"peter",
         "BookDescription":"a wall in the rainy season where all "
      },
      {
         "UserId":"75",
         "BookTitle":"who am i",
         "BookGenre":"inspiration",
         "BookWriter":"modi",
         "BookDescription":"this book is all about the struggle one faces all his life.no matter what he does he never get any attention"
      },
      {
         "UserId":"75",
         "BookTitle":"a walk to remember",
         "BookGenre":"romance",
         "BookWriter":"peter",
         "BookDescription":"a wall in the rainy season where all "
      },
      {
         "UserId":"74",
         "BookTitle":"who am i",
         "BookGenre":"inspiration",
         "BookWriter":"modi",
         "BookDescription":"this book is all about the struggle one faces all his life.no matter what he does he never get any attention"
      },
      {
         "UserId":"74",
         "BookTitle":"a walk to remember",
         "BookGenre":"romance",
         "BookWriter":"peter",
         "BookDescription":"a wall in the rainy season where all "
      },
      {
         "UserId":"73",
         "BookTitle":"who am i",
         "BookGenre":"inspiration",
         "BookWriter":"modi",
         "BookDescription":"this book is all about the struggle one faces all his life.no matter what he does he never get any attention"
      },
      {
         "UserId":"73",
         "BookTitle":"a walk to remember",
         "BookGenre":"romance",
         "BookWriter":"peter",
         "BookDescription":"a wall in the rainy season where all "
      }
   ]
}
```

**PHP API:**

```
 $personal = $db->prepare('select Id,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Gender,Location,Email,Mobile from personaldetails ORDER BY Id DESC');
    $personal->execute();
    $json_data=array();



    foreach($personal as $row)//foreach loop  
    {  

        $json_array['id']=$row['Id'];  
        $json_array['FirstName']=$row['FirstName'];  
        $json_array['MiddleName']=$row['MiddleName'];  
        $json_array['LastName']=$row['LastName']; 
        $json_array['Gender']=$row['Gender']; 
        $json_array['Location']=$row['Location']; 
        $json_array['Email']=$row['Email']; 
        $json_array['Mobile']=$row['Mobile'];
        array_push($json_data,$json_array);  

}  

    $books = $db->prepare('select UserId,BookTitle,BookGenre,BookWriter,BookDescription from bookdetails ORDER BY UserId Desc'); 
    $books->execute();
    $json_data1=array();

     //$bookNo = 0;
    foreach($books as $row)//foreach loop  
    {  
        //$bookNo++;
        //$json_array1['BookNo']= $bookNo;  
        $json_array1['UserId']=$row['UserId']; 
        $json_array1['BookTitle']=$row['BookTitle']; 
        $json_array1['BookGenre']=$row['BookGenre'];  
        $json_array1['BookWriter']=$row['BookWriter']; 
        $json_array1['BookDescription']=$row['BookDescription']; 

    //here pushing the values in to an array  
    array_push($json_data1,$json_array1);  

}  

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array("personaldetails"=>$json_data,"bookdetails"=>$json_data1));
```

**JavaScript in HTML**

```
<script>
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        if (data) {
            var personalArr = (data.personaldetails).length;
            console.log(personalArr);
            var bookArr = (data.bookdetails).length;
            console.log(bookArr);
            for (var i = 0; i < personalArr; i++) {
                var a = data.personaldetails[i].Id;
                $("#personalDiv").append('<div>' + '<p>' + 'FirstName:' + data.personaldetails[i].FirstName + 
                                         '<br/>' + 'MiddleName:' + data.personaldetails[i].MiddleName + 
                                         '<br/>' + 'LastName:' + data.personaldetails[i].LastName + 
                                         '<br/>' + 'Location:' + data.personaldetails[i].Location + 
                                         '<br/>' + 'Email:' + data.personaldetails[i].Email + 
                                         '<br/>' + 'Mobile:' + data.personaldetails[i].Mobile + '<br/>' + '</p>' + '</div>');
                for (var j = 0; j < bookArr; j++) {
                    var b = data.bookdetails[j].UserId;
                    if (a == b) {
                        $("#personalDiv").append('<div>' + '<p>' + 'BookTitle:' + data.bookdetails[j].BookTitle + 
                                                 '<br/>' + 'BookGenre:' + data.bookdetails[j].BookGenre + 
                                                 '<br/>' + 'BookWriter:' + data.bookdetails[j].BookWriter + 
                                                 '<br/>' + 'BookDescription:' + data.bookdetails[j].BookDescription + 
                                                 '<br/>' + '</p>' + '</div>');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(data);
        alert("Roger that" + JSON.stringify(data));
    });

    $(function() {
        loadData();
    });
</script>
<div class="grid" id="postjson"></div>
<div class="grid" id="personalDiv"></div>
```

Please give me some alternative solution two cause but my approach is very time consuming at large data context.

here is my desired output( all in single html div) :

[image]

Comment: do you ever get inside `if(a==b)`? In other words, do you find a matching id?

Comment: no i tnink, thats why i am asking for some alternative.

Comment: why not use mysql `JOIN` to fetch your data ?

Comment: Without going into much detail, there is something that you can do to improve the performance of your code: do not call `append` within your `for` loops. First concatenate the `div`s you want and then, outside the `for` loops, do the append. (Reason: just hit the DOM once instead of multiple times within the loop).

Comment: @CodeGodie cuase join will duplicate my personal information data into next 4 rows. 
example :- (personal, book_row1), (personal, book_row2), (personal, book_row3), (personal, book_row4), (personal, book_row5).
how would i display it in html?

Comment: provide us with a sample of your desired output

Comment: @CodeGodie i have attached the desired output image. 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `JOINs` in your mysql query, its the proper and most efficient way. Once you have your result set, you can then iterate over the results and clean it, re-organize it to match how you want your front-end to see it. I would do it in this manner:

SQL:

```
SELECT
    p.Id, p.FirstName, p.MiddleName, p.LastName, p.Gender, p.Location, p.Email, p.Mobile,
    b.BookTitle, b.BookGenre, b.BookWriter, b.BookDescription
FROM personaldetails AS p
LEFT JOIN bookdetails AS b ON b.UserId = p.Id
ORDER BY p.Id DESC
```

Sample DB Result:

```
//sample
$db_result_set = [
    [
        "Id" => 1,
        "FirstName" => "John",
        "MiddleName" => "Bob",
        "LastName" => "Doe",
        "BookTitle" => "The Boy",
        "BookGenre" => "Fiction",
        "BookWriter" => "Mark Doe",
        "BookDescription" => "about some boy",
    ],
    [
        "Id" => 1,
        "FirstName" => "John",
        "MiddleName" => "Bob",
        "LastName" => "Doe",
        "BookTitle" => "The Girl",
        "BookGenre" => "Fiction",
        "BookWriter" => "Jane Doe",
        "BookDescription" => "about some girl",
    ],
    [
        "Id" => 1,
        "FirstName" => "John",
        "MiddleName" => "Bob",
        "LastName" => "Doe",
        "BookTitle" => "The Man",
        "BookGenre" => "Fiction",
        "BookWriter" => "Pat Doe",
        "BookDescription" => "about some man",
    ],
    [
        "Id" => 23,
        "FirstName" => "Bobby",
        "MiddleName" => "Bob",
        "LastName" => "Doe",
        "BookTitle" => "The Girl",
        "BookGenre" => "Fiction",
        "BookWriter" => "Jane Doe",
        "BookDescription" => "about some girl",
    ],
    [
        "Id" => 23,
        "FirstName" => "Bobby",
        "MiddleName" => "Bob",
        "LastName" => "Doe",
        "BookTitle" => "The Man",
        "BookGenre" => "Fiction",
        "BookWriter" => "Pat Doe",
        "BookDescription" => "about some man",
    ]
];
```

PHP:

```
$final = [];
foreach ($db_result_set as $u) {
    if (!is_array($final[$u["Id"]])) {
        $final[$u["Id"]]= [
            "Id" => $u["Id"],
            "FirstName" => $u["FirstName"],
            "MiddleName" => $u["MiddleName"],
            "LastName" => $u["LastName"],
        ];
    }
    $final[$u["Id"]]["books"][] = [
        "BookTitle" => $u["BookTitle"],
        "BookGenre" => $u["BookGenre"],
        "BookWriter" => $u["BookWriter"],
        "BookDescription" => $u["BookDescription"],
    ];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($final);
echo "</pre>";
```

RESULT:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [FirstName] => John
            [MiddleName] => Bob
            [LastName] => Doe
            [books] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [BookTitle] => The Boy
                            [BookGenre] => Fiction
                            [BookWriter] => Mark Doe
                            [BookDescription] => about some boy
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [BookTitle] => The Girl
                            [BookGenre] => Fiction
                            [BookWriter] => Jane Doe
                            [BookDescription] => about some girl
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [BookTitle] => The Man
                            [BookGenre] => Fiction
                            [BookWriter] => Pat Doe
                            [BookDescription] => about some man
                        )

                )

        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 23
            [FirstName] => Bobby
            [MiddleName] => Bob
            [LastName] => Doe
            [books] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [BookTitle] => The Girl
                            [BookGenre] => Fiction
                            [BookWriter] => Jane Doe
                            [BookDescription] => about some girl
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [BookTitle] => The Man
                            [BookGenre] => Fiction
                            [BookWriter] => Pat Doe
                            [BookDescription] => about some man
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Now you can easily send this to your front end for a better iteration and rendering.

Comment: Thank You so much  for this help :) can you please put some sample code of rendering this data in html through javascript .it would be more than awesome. 
and  after encoding as json, why is it giving some notice "Notice: Undefined offset: 80 in /opt/lampp/htdocs on line 15" ? please look into this. Thanks in advance!